# FutureWarning when creating an empty GeoSeries

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to create an empty `GeoSeries` which is later populated with geometries:

```
import geopandas as gpd
x = gpd.GeoSeries()
```

This gives me the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=name, **kwargs)
```

I tried specifying a `dtype` to silence the warning as instructed:

```
import geopandas as gpd
x = gpd.GeoSeries(dtype='geometry')
```

But this still gives me the exact same `FutureWarning`.

What can I do to silence the warning?

### Edit

I've also tried specifying a different `dtype`, but the warning still shows:

```
x = gpd.GeoSeries(dtype='float64')
C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py:207: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=name, **kwargs)

x = gpd.GeoSeries(dtype='int')
C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py:207: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=name, **kwargs)

x = gpd.GeoSeries(dtype='int64')
C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py:207: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=name, **kwargs)

x = gpd.GeoSeries(dtype='str')
C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py:207: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=name, **kwargs)

x = gpd.GeoSeries(dtype='object')
C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py:207: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=name, **kwargs)

x = gpd.GeoSeries(dtype='geometry')
C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py:207: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=name, **kwargs)
```

### Versions

In case it helps, the versions I'm using:

```
gpd.show_versions()

SYSTEM INFO
-----------
python     : 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable : xxx
machine    : xxx

GEOS, GDAL, PROJ INFO
---------------------
GEOS       : None
GEOS lib   : None
GDAL       : 3.0.2
GDAL data dir: None
PROJ       : 6.2.1
PROJ data dir: xxx

PYTHON DEPENDENCIES
-------------------
geopandas  : 0.9.0
pandas     : 1.5.2
fiona      : 1.8.13.post1
numpy      : 1.23.4
shapely    : 1.8.4
rtree      : 0.9.7
pyproj     : 2.6.1.post1
matplotlib : 3.5.1
mapclassify: 2.4.3
geopy      : None
psycopg2   : None
geoalchemy2: None
pyarrow    : None
pygeos     : None
```

Comment: Warnings aren’t errors - they’re just warnings. If you’d like to suppress them, you can use the warnings control routines in the warnings library

Comment: the most obvious thing is that pandas is unto date and geopandas is old.  I'd start by updating geopandas.  FYI FutureWarnings can quite often be ignored, then if you still see take a look at a number of the FutureWarning clearing issues on GitHub There are a few fresh ones with pandas 1.5